# ¿que puedo aprender para poder utilizar hack the box?

Tags: hack

E buscado información, pero la mayoría está en otro idioma o es difícil de entender, si alguien me ayuda a como iniciar le agradecería.

Comment: Esta pregunta puede acabar cerrada, recomiendo leas [ask]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bienvenido a la Comunidad.

- Lo principal que te recomiendo es aprender inglés. Es primordial para
  cualquier escenario de IT.
- Luego, es recomendable saber o tener una buena lógica de
  programación. (Puedes aprender lenguajes tipados, multipropósitos,
  alto, bajo y medio nivel)
- Tener una muy buena base de Sistemas Operativos (Los más populares
  como Windows, Linux y MacOS)
- Un buen conocimieno de Networking también es necesario (Capas, modelo OSI, direcciones IP estática y dinámica, con eso bastará)
- Y un buen conocimiento de criptografía y criptoanálisis te ayudará bastante.

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta no debería ser respondida pues no se ajusta a [ask], por otro lado considero que dado lo amplio de tu respuesta tal vez dejarlo mejor como comentario